# Undoing permission change of my entire drive

Tags: 13.04, permissions

For some stupid reason I excecuted **sudo chmod -R 755 /**. Now none of my software will run. Can I fix this without reinstalling? And if yes, how?

Comment: `bash` should have prevented you from operating on `/`... but often computers will do this sort of thing if they detect that you don't have a backup of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no real undo to chmod. If yours is a reasonably new install we could give you a list of all main files/directories and you could try to restore permissions one by one, but sincerely that would be a hell of a job.

You could better boot from live CD, backup all your stuff and re-install.